# Check if Java array contains n amount of a specific integer

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a method available where you can check if an array contains n amount of a specific integer.

So say we have the array:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2 , 3 , 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
```

Can we check if arr contains 2 5's. Or if arr contains 3 2's.

Comment: Yes we can (huh, it sounds like something familiar) ! What did you tru so far ?

Comment: No out of the box method, you have to do it by yourself (or use a guava Multiset)

Comment: Cool, just wondering if I had to make one myself

Comment: In any case, it's a three-liner or so.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify `RC's` comment. You could use Guava's ImmutableMultiset and Multiset as follows:

```
Multiset<Integer> set = ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(myarray);
int countOf5s = set.count(5);
```

This is not the obvious simple answer here, but I love Guava so thought I would put in the plug.

[ImmutableMultset.copyOf()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultiset.html#copyOf(E[]))

[Multiset.count()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#count(java.lang.Object))

Comment: This won't work for a primitive array and if OP had a reference-typed array, then `Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(myarray), 5)` would do it for him, and more performantly so.

Comment: I forgot about `frequency`. Thanks. However, IMHO performance could be argued as this is probably only more performant if doing a single lookup. If doing more than one count check, I think the set is probably faster overall. WRT the `int[]`, Guava's `Ints.asList` would work well there.

Comment: For smallish primitive arrays you'll need a whole lotta lookups to beat a three-liner method specialized for the case. Especially considering that the whole array will be in the L1 cache, and even more so if the requirement is to check whether the array has *at least* the requested amount of values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to count occurrences of *one* element, there's no reason to build a `Multiset` to count all the elements, though Guava will still help you...

```
int countOf5s = Collections.frequency(Ints.asList(intArray), 5);
```